# Quotient Ring multiplication

Tags: ring-theory

Please help I’m very confused about this.
If $[r]$ and $[s]$ are two cosets of the set $R/A$ (Where $A$ is an ideal of the ring $R$) why are we allowed to define $[r]*[s]=[rs]$ when we only know that $[r]*[s]$ is a subset of $[rs]$?

Comment: $r, s, $ and $rs$ are elements of $R$; $[r], [s]$, and $[rs]$ are elements of $R/A$; I'm not sure why you said $[r]*[s]$ is a subset of $[rs]$

Comment: as an example, take $R=\mathbb Z$, $A=17\mathbb Z$, $r=2$, $s=3$, $rs=6$; $[r]=r+17\mathbb Z$, $s]=s+17\mathbb Z$, $[rs]=rs+17\mathbb Z$

Comment: Let $a,b \in A$. We have $(r+a) \in [r]$ and $(s+b) \in [s]$ so $(r+a)*(s+b)=rs+(as+rb+ab)  \in [rs]$

Comment: That is correct

Comment: We want the multiplication $[r] *[s] $ to be in $R/A$ so we define  it to be $[rs]$ which gives as a homomorphism from $R$ to $R/A$

Comment: My question is can we show this the other way around so that they are equal and not one being a subset.

Comment: @Anteater23 $[r] *[s] $ is not defined to be $\{(r+a) *(s+b) : a, b\in A\} $, because we want $[r] *[s] $ to definitely be a coset so we define $[r] *[s] = [rs] $ and such definition is well defined. You can't prove a definition.

Comment: That makes sense now ty.